# How to check internal size parameters that controls example generation

Tags: python-hypothesis

In PropEr, there's an internal variable called `Size` that represents the size of generated example.

For instance, when we have 2 variables and would like to make them proportional each other, PropEr let you write the following test:

```erlang
prop_profile2() ->
    ?FORALL(Profile, [{name, string()},
                      {age, pos_integer()},
                      {bio, ?SIZED(Size, resize(Size*35, string()))}],
        begin
            NameLen = to_range(10, length(proplists:get_value(name, Profile))),
            BioLen = to_range(300, length(proplists:get_value(bio, Profile))),
            aggregate([{name, NameLen}, {bio, BioLen}], true)
        end).
```

In this test, the internal variable `Size` holds the internal size of `string()` (string value generator), so what `?SIZED(Size, resize(Size*35, string()))` does here is make this part 35 times larger than `string()` called next to `name` atom.

I tried to something similar to this with Hypothesis, but what I could come up with was the following:

```py
@composite
def profiles(draw: DrawFn):
    name = draw(text(max_size=10))
    name_len = len(name)
    age = draw(integers(min_value=1, max_value=150))
    bio_len = 35 * name_len
    bio = draw(text(min_size=bio_len, max_size=bio_len))
    return Profile(name, age, bio)
```

Are there any other smarter ways to have proportional sizes among multiple variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you're testing actually *requires* these proportions, your test looks good, though I think a direct translation of your PropEr code would have `bio = draw(text(min_size=bio_len, max_size=max(bio_len, 300)))`?  As-is, you'd never be able to find bugs with even-length bios, or short bios, and so on.

This points to a more fundamental question: why do you want proportional inputs in the first place?

Hypothesis style is to just express the limits of your allowed input directly - "builds(name=text(max_size=10), age=integers(1, 150), bio=text(max_size=300))` - and let the framework give you diverse and error-inducing inputs from whatever weird edge case it finds.  (note: if you're checking the distribution, do so over 10,000+ examples - each run of 100 won't look very diverse)

PropEr style often adds further constraints on the inputs, in order to produce more realistic data or guide generation to particular areas of interest.  I think this is a mistake: my goal is not to generate realistic data, it's to maximize the probability that I find a bug - ignoring part of the input space can only hurt - and then to minimize the expected time to do so (a topic too large for this answer).